# Replacing occurrences of "\:"

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift4

I'm trying to replace occurrences of `:` with `\:` but I'm getting the **Invalid escape sequence in literal** error.
I've tried escaping with `\\\:`, but it's replacing the occurrence with the double bar:

I need to get:

```
2000:2018-07-25T10\:31\:06Z:2018-07-30
```

from original str:

```
2000:2018-07-25T10:31:06Z:2018-07-30
```

and I'm getting:

```
2000:2018-07-25T10\\\:31\\\:06Z:2018-07-30
```

My code:

```
newString.replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: "\:") //Invalid escape sequence in literal

newString.replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: "\\:") //not quite want I need
```

Comment: @Moritz after the edit now the string has an invalid scape sequence

Comment: @Moritz I think that his intent was to ask how to manually add or remove the escape from a json string which it is not necessary.

Comment: I understood your edit. OP needs to learn how to use triple double quote marks https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0168-multi-line-string-literals.md

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding on the question, my questions was based on the fact that I thought the simple solution of escaping with double backslash will work, but it isn't.  What do you mean with triple double quote marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape backslashes with another backslash. So if you want to replace `":"` with `"\:"`you need to replace with `"\\:"`.

```
let backslashString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: "\\:")
```

Comment: This is giving me `"2000\\:2018-07-25T10\\:31\\:06Z\\:2018-07-30"` when I print it out on the debugger, and I need it to be only one backslash, I have the feeling I'm missing something here :/

Comment: Well, you are right indeed. The strange thing is if I print out with `print()` function I get the correct string with one backslash, but if I print it with "po" on the debugger I get the string with double backslashes. Interesting

Answer (score -1):

We can do this way:

let OrginalStr = "2000:2018-07-25T10:31:06Z:2018-07-30"

let strTobeReplace = "\:"

let resultStr = OrginalStr.replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: "(strTobeReplace)")

print(resultStr)

Output:

"2000:2018-07-25T10:31:06Z:2018-07-30"