# remove backslash quotation from url string

Tags: json, swift

How can I replace `\"` with `"` in my URL as string?
It's a URL of my get request and after "value=" I put a JSON as string:

> [api//AppVersion/?value={\n  \"AccountType\" : 3,\n  \"FCMToken\" : \"fNqcy_OZEAsKDDK\",\n  \"AppIdentifier\" : \"ir.gcoapp\",\n  \"VersionCode\" : 3,\n  \"UserId\" : 486167,\n  \"VersionName\" : \"3.0\"\n}"][1]

I use the following code to generate this URL:

```
let jsonPostfix = Serialization.ToJson(object: requestModel)
url = "\(Configuration.ApiURL)/\(controller)/?value=\(jsonPostfix)"
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47799046/replacing-occurrences-of/47800183#47800183

Comment: no that does not work, I need something like this url.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: """), I can do this url.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "") but it remove the "

Comment: As said in the reply I linked, you need to ESCAPE BACKSLASHES to use them in a string, as they are an escape character themselves. So whenever you want Swift to think about the character "\" you need to write it as "\\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace \" with " by doing this:

`url.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\"", with: "\"")`

`\\` means `\`,  `\"` means `"`. The backslash lets Swift know you want to use the character after it as a character and not as an escape.

Comment: look like the problem back to alamofire reading url, backslash don't remove in alamofire url string

Comment: Also, how are you retrieving the string you posted in your original question? If you are posting the result via a `print` call the quotes are added by the print function, it's not _actually_ in the string. IIRC you can see the actual raw string by using the `po foo` command in lldb (the command line log you can use after adding a breakpoint where you get the URL)